# Search bar added in navigation titleView

Tags: ios

1. Search bar as a navigationitem titleView on first view controller.

2.while clicking search button on keypad Pushing the second view controller

issue: after pushing the some black line is moving from right side to left side in second view controller.. please check the attached images for better understanding

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 UIViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchDetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

[FirstViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTq52.png)

[Second View controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL7RN.png)

Comment: You need to show code.

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: Are you facing this in simulator or device?

Comment: Both in simulator and device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue.You should dismiss searchbar keyboard before push.

> [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

UIViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchDetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```